# Cannot convert type 'WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord' to 'int'

Tags: c#, sql, webmatrix

Cannot convert type 'WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord' to 'int' exception shows up when i try to output value of QueryValue method to int?

```
public class SaveCustomerData : IDisposable
{
private readonly string _connectionString;
private readonly Database _db;

public SaveCustomerData(string connectionString)
{
    _connectionString = connectionString;
    _db = Database.Open(connectionString);
}

public void Insert(string fname, string lname, string phone, string cellno, DateTime dob, string gender, string address, string address2, string creditno, string city, string postalcode, string email) {
    var uid = Convert.ToInt32(_db.QuerySingle("SELECT UserID FROM UserProfile WHERE Email=@0",email));



    _db.Execute("INSERT INTO Customer_Table (customer_fname, customer_lname, customer_phone, customer_mobile, customer_dob, customer_gender, customer_address, customer_address2, customer_credit_no, customer_city, customer_postal, UserID) VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12)",
        fname, lname, phone, cellno, dob, gender, address, address2, creditno, city, postalcode, uid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this:

```
_db.QuerySingle("SELECT UserID FROM UserProfile WHERE Email=@0",email)
   .Item["UserID"];
```

in order you get the value of the `UserID` is returned. You got the error you posted in your question, because your query returns an object of type `WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord`, which

> Represents a data record by using a custom type descriptor and the
>   capabilities of the Dynamic Language Runtime (DLR).

as it is stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.dynamicrecord%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) and not the value of `UserID`.

In order you get the value of a certain column in the record that is returned after the execution of `_db.QuerySingle(...)`, you have two options:

- `Item[Int32]`,

> Returns the value of a column in the DynamicRecord instance using the specified index.

and

- `Item[string]`,

> Returns the value of a column in the DynamicRecord instance using the specified name.

Comment: I just updated my post. You can take the value using the [0], that will return you the value in the column with index 0, or you could retrieve the value using the name of the column.